# mysql privileges are not working correctly

Tags: mysql, database

I executed, 
grant all privileges on mythconverg.* to 'mythtv'@'localhost' identified by 'mythtv';

however when I execute, 
mysql -u mythtv -p -h localhost mythtvconverg

I get,
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'mythtv'@'localhost' to database 'mythtvconverg'

It's not supposed to work this way but it is, what's wrong?

Comment: I got it working now by rebooting, apparently FLUSH PRIVILEGES isn't enough you have to actually reboot.

Comment: Or because mythconverg.* won't allow you to access a schema called mythtvconverg.  One has "tv" in it and one doesn't

Answer (score 0):

to solve, ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'mythtv'@'localhost' to database 'mythtvconverg'

you need to reboot